# Procedure or function 'Itinerary_getitinerary' expects parameter '@name', which was not supplied

Tags: biztalk

I am using your BRI extension and got the following error. How can I debug this? Thanks!

Procedure or function 'Itinerary_getitinerary' expects parameter '@name', which was not supplied.

Answer (score 1):

For debugging, your best bet is to enable ESB Toolkit tracing: http://midheach.wordpress.com/2011/02/28/tracing-with-esb-toolkit-2-1/

This will cause ESB Toolkit to output debugging messages to the event log as it processes a message.

As for your specific error message, either the resolver connection string is wrong or the BRE policy rule has an error that is causing itinerary resolution to fail.